# JQuery ui autocomplete in a MVC partial view only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I've been trying to get autocomplete to work for my partial view using JQuery ui. The partial view is updated using AJAX.

The problem is that the autocomplete only works up until the point where the partial view is updated.

This is my partial view

```
<div id="tagList">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToTagList", new { urlLocation = Model.UrlLocation }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "tagList" }))
{
    if (Model.TagList != null)
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag.Text, "Tags", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 300px;">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "search_term" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#search_term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Tag/SearchAutoComplete",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Text, value: item.Text };
                }));

            }
        });
    },
  });
});
```

and this is my autocomplete search action

```
        public JsonResult SearchAutoComplete(string term)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = RavenDbConfig.RavenDBDocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var results = session.Query<Tag>().Where(x => x.Text.StartsWith(term)).ToList();
            return Json(results,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

So, my question is, how can i make this work even after the partial view has been updated once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is when you reload your `PartialView` you basicaly delete some part of **DOM** in your html document and create new one. And all your bindings that you add in `$(document).ready()` event will be lost.

One of the posible solutions for this problem is to place your autocomplete init code in addition to `.ready()` event in jquery `.ajaxSuccess()` [global event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) becouse you reload your `PartialViews` via **Ajax**. Like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $("#search_term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Tag/SearchAutoComplete",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Text, value: item.Text };
                }));

            }
        });
    },
  });
});
```

That way you will init your autocomplete every time you reload `PartialView`.